# Getting specific ranges Vba

Tags: vba

I have four data sets that I combined together onto a separate worksheet. Unfortunately, I cannot manually combine these four together. I grabbed each of the data sets and pasted them one on top of each other (Data 1 then Data 2 then Data 3 then Data 4) After pasting all the data onto the worksheet, I need to make some changes to each of the data sets. I would like to add another column that tags on where the data comes from (If its from data set 1 then it will say "Data 1"). At this moment, I dont know how to grab the proper range. I also can't just get the row numbers because each of the data set is fluid and will have added/deleted rows in the future.

```
'copying the data to the report - data 1
 cashData.Range("B5:B" & rgCash_lastrow).Copy cnCS.Range("E3")
 cnCS.Range("E3:E" & cnCS.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) = "Data 1"

Dim report_lastrow As Long
report_lastrow = cnCS.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).row

'copying the data to the report - data 2
safeData.Range("B5:B" & rgSafe_lastrow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & 
report_lastrow + 1)
'What range can i put in to get range = "Data 2"
 
Dim report_lastrow2 As Long
report_lastrow2 = cnCS.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).row

'copying the data to the report - data 3
pictetData.Range("B5:B" & rgPictet_lastrow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & report_lastrow2 + 1)
'What range can i put in to get range = "Data 3" 

Dim report_lastrow3 As Long
report_lastrow3 = cnCS.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).row

'copying the data to the report - data 4
rothData.Range("B5:B" & rgRoth_lastrow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & report_lastrow3 + 1)
'What range can i put in to get range = "Data 4"
```

Comment: Please be more specific or no one can help you. For instance, how do you paste your workbook data? Do you leave an empty row between each one? Do you put each one in a separate table? Also, why not paste each data set on separate worksheets?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I made some changes. please let me know what you think

Comment: You do not show us all your code... I cannot understand why. Where does your code calculate `rgCash_lastrow`? This have to be calculated after each copying.

Comment: Do you want putting that marker in column G:G?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way/code. I (only) suppose that you try placing the tags in column "G:G":

```
Sub writeInARange()
    'your existing code where the sheets objects are declared and Set
    '...............................
     Dim lastRow As Long, report_lastrow As Long
   
     lastRow = cashData.Range("B" & cashData.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     cashData.Range("B5:B" & lastRow).Copy cnCS.Range("E3")
     cnCS.Range("G3:G" & cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).value = "Data 1"
    
    'copying the data to the report - data 2
    lastRow = safeData.Range("B" & safeData.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    report_lastrow = cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    safeData.Range("B5:B" & lastRow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & report_lastrow + 1)
    cnCS.Range("G3:G" & cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).value = "Data 2"
    
    'copying the data to the report - data 3
    lastRow = pictetData.Range("B" & pictetData.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    report_lastrow = cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    pictetData.Range("B5:B" & lastRow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & report_lastrow + 1)
    cnCS.Range("G3:G" & cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).value = "Data 3"
    
    'copying the data to the report - data 4
    lastRow = rothData.Range("B" & rothData.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    report_lastrow = cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    rothData.Range("B5:B" & lastRow).Copy cnCS.Range("E" & report_lastrow + 1)
    cnCS.Range("G3:G" & cnCS.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).value = "Data 4"
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work, if I correctly understood what you need.

Comment: @briguy Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?